How to Modify Response Status Code to 200 in Azure API Management Policy
I'm working with an Azure API Management service and have the following policy configuration:
<!-- Policies are applied in the order they appear. 
     Position <base/> inside a section to inherit policies from the outer scope. 
     Comments within policies are not preserved. -->
<!-- Add policies as children to the <inbound>, <outbound>, <backend>, and <on-error> elements -->
<policies>
    <!-- Throttle, authorize, validate, cache, or transform the requests -->
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://xxx" />
    </inbound>
    <!-- Control if and how the requests are forwarded to services -->
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <!-- Customize the responses -->
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <!-- Handle exceptions and customize error responses -->
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

My backend service returns a status code of 201, but I need the response returned to the client to be 200. How can I modify the response status code in the  policy to achieve this?
Thank you for your help!
UPDATE: I was able to make it work:
<!--
    - Policies are applied in the order they appear.
    - Position <base/> inside a section to inherit policies from the outer scope.
    - Comments within policies are not preserved.
-->
<!-- Add policies as children to the <inbound>, <outbound>, <backend>, and <on-error> elements -->
<policies>
    <!-- Throttle, authorize, validate, cache, or transform the requests -->
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <!-- Control if and how the requests are forwarded to services  -->
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <!-- Customize the responses -->
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 201)">
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <!-- Handle exceptions and customize error responses  -->
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>


Is it working now? @DeadlyMuffin

Yes, the problem I had was that I was receiving a 308 code first and then a 201, so the policy did not work correctly. After making some tweaks it is working now
